# IDXGIOutput::GetDisplayModeList Finds No Display Modes

Tags: c++, directx

I am trying to get a list of all the possible resolutions for a `IDXGI_OUTPUT*`. To do this, I found the `IDXGIOutput::GetDisplayModeList` API. Unfortunately, there are almost no examples of usage that I could find online. I tried the one on MSDN, and it failed to find any display modes (`num` is 0)

```
UINT num = 0;
DXGI_FORMAT format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
UINT flags         = DXGI_ENUM_MODES_INTERLACED;

pOutput->GetDisplayModeList( format, flags, &num, 0);

DXGI_MODE_DESC * pDescs = new DXGI_MODE_DESC[num];
pOutput->GetDisplayModeList( format, flags, &num, pDescs);
```

I noticed MSDN recommends to use `GetDisplayModeList1()` instead, so I tried that as well and `num` still is 0. I have also verified that the `IDXGI_OUTPUT*` is completely valid. I am at a loss what to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for all display modes that support the `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT` format. This format is never supported (at least at the time of this answer posting) for "display scan-out".

The only currently defined "display scan-out" DXGI formats are:

```
DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT
DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM
DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10_XR_BIAS_A2_UNORM
DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM
DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB
DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM_SRGB
```

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/direct3d12/hardware-feature-levels#hardware-support-for-dxgi-formats).

Comment: Even with `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM` (note X instead of A) I got `*pNumModes==0` for some GPU.

Comment: `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM` is not part of the 'required to support' for scan-out, although an individual vendor could report support for it.

Comment: Exactly. I pointed it out as a potential gotcha, because one may be confused for the other.